# GetTempPath shows different user then current

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, mfc

I am using MFC on Windows 8. When I get `Temp` path, it contains path to a different user account:

```
  C:\Users\AACE~1\AppData\Temp
```

The permission to write to a file is closed and `CFile` fails. My account is:

```
  C:\Users\Dmitry
```

I debug and launch application under my account. What is the problem? Also, I am running on Windows 8 with only one user account.

Comment: Have you checked environment variables to make sure Temp is pointing to where it should?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364992.aspx) for this function describes how it works:

> The GetTempPath function checks for the existence of environment
>   variables in the following order and uses the first path found:
>
> 1. The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
> 2. The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
> 3. The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
> 4. The Windows directory.

So, the likely cause is that you have a mis-configuration of your environment. Check the value of the `TMP` and `TEMP` environment variables.